# How can i convert my existing mongo db query in to spring boot using aggregation class

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I wrote mongodb query. And am facing some issue while converting it in spring boot using aggregation class.So, please help me, i want it to convert it in spring boot using aggregation class.

```
db.api_audit.aggregate([{

  $match: {
      merchant_id: '015994832961',
      request_time: {$gte: ISODate("2017-05-11T00:00:00.0Z"), 
          $lt: ISODate("2017-05-12T00:00:00.0Z")}}},
{  
   $group: 
    {
        _id: {
        SERVICE_NAME: "$service_name",

        STATUS: "$status"
    },
    count: {
        "$sum": 1
    }
}
}, {


 $group: {
    _id: "$_id.SERVICE_NAME",

    STATUSCOUNT: {
        $push: {
            Service_name: "$_id.STATUS",
            count: "$count"
        }
    }
}
 },
 { $sort : { "STATUSCOUNT.count" : -1} }
  ])
```

Below is the db query response

```
{
"_id" : "sendOTP",
"STATUSCOUNT" : [ 
    {
        "status" : "SUCCESS",
        "count" : 2.0
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First you create all the required operations and then you add them to an aggregation pipeline. Then you feed it to an autowired mongotemplate.

Something like this:

```
@Autowired
private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

void aggregate()
{

    Criteria match = where("merchant_id").is("015994832961").andOperator(where("request_time").gte(Date.parse("2017-05-11T00:00:00.0Z")).lt(Date.parse("2017-05-11T00:00:00.0Z")));
    GroupOperation groupOperation1 = group(fields().and("SERVICE_NAME").and("STATUS")).count().as("count");
    GroupOperation groupOperation2 = ...//(not sure how push works here, but it should not be hard to figure out)
    SortOperation sortOperation = sort(DESC, "STATUSCOUNT.count");

    Aggregation aggegation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, groupOperation1, groupOperation2, sortOperation);

    List<Result> results = mongoTemplate.aggegate(aggregation, ObjectOfCollectionToRunOn.class, Result.class).getMappedResults();
}
```